# Elastic suggest autocompletion : resut not expected

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, elasticsearch-suggester

I'm struggling to understand a result I'm getting while using the suggest API.

The goal is that I don't want that this result to be returned.

How to reproduce - here is my mapping :

```
PUT /movies
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "true_false_filter": {
          "type": "keep",
          "keep_words": [
            "true",
            "false"
          ]
        },
        "french_elision": {
          "type": "elision",
          "articles_case": false,
          "articles": [
            "puisqu"
          ]
        },
        "french_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "light_french"
        },
        "organic-dictionary": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "expand": true,
          "lenient": true,
          "synonyms": [
            "non bio"
          ]
        },
        "french_stop_filter": {
          "type": "stop",
          "ignore_case": true,
          "stopwords": "_french_"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "lowercase_stop_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "lowercase",
          "filter": [
            "french_stop_filter"
          ]
        },
        "lowercase_asciifolding": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "asciifolding",
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "french_analyzer_custom": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "asciifolding",
            "lowercase",
            "french_elision",
            "french_stemmer"
          ]
        },
        "custom_organic_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "asciifolding",
            "lowercase",
            "french_elision",
            "organic-dictionary",
            "true_false_filter",
            "unique"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "attr": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "french_analyzer_custom"
      },
      "brand_name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "brand_name_suggest": {
        "type": "completion",
        "analyzer": "lowercase_stop_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "lowercase_asciifolding",
        "preserve_separators": false,
        "preserve_position_increments": false,
        "max_input_length": 50
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I put a document in the index:

```
POST /movies/_doc/1001
{
    "brand_name": "A LE MOUTON HUILE D'OLIVE",
    "brand_name_suggest": [
      "A LE MOUTON HUILE D'OLIVE"
    ]
}
```

Then my search :

```
GET movies/_search
{
  "explain": true, 
  "suggest": {
    "completer": {
      "text": "amo",
      "completion": {
        "field": "brand_name_suggest",
        "size": 20,
        "skip_duplicates": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My issue : why is this document found while searching for "amo"?

And how to prevent it to be returned ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `brand_name_suggest` uses the `lowercase_stop_analyzer` which removes French stop words, `A LE MOUTON HUILE D'OLIVE` would be analyzed as `a, mouton, huile, olive`, i.e. `LE` is getting removed.

So at search time, when you type `amo`, it matches the first two tokens, hence why you're getting this document. If you want to prevent this, you need to remove the `french_stop_filter` from your index-time analyzer.

Besides another issue that might come to bug you later is that your search analyzer `lowercase_asciifolding` does asciifolding but your index-time analyzer doesn't, so if you index words with accent, you might not find them at search time either.